# Paginating in aggregation in elasticsearch 2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-aggregation

I would like to paginate aggregation in 2.1. I know that it is not possible to paginate terms  aggregation in elastic 2.1 and if client side implements it, it will not be efficient. But I would still like some idea about how can I go about implementing it myself? The main problem I am facing is, how can I maintain a pointer to the last bucket I retrieved on previous page?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to migrate to a newer version of ES?

Comment: Yes. But it would take a lot of time. I kind of need this implementation now.